# Maximum cut optimisation

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider the algorithm below which calculates a V cut

- Initialize $V_1 = V$ et $V_2 = \emptyset$
- Attempt to improve the value of the cut in any of the following ways

  Check if there is a $v \in V_1$  such as $c(V_1-\{v\}, V_2 \cup \{v\}) > c(V_1,V_2)$

  If yes continue with $V_1 = V_1 -\{v\}$ et $V_2 = V_2 \cup \{v\}$.

  Check if there is a $v \in V_2$ such as $c(V_1 \cup \{v\}, V_2 - \{v\}) > c(V_1,V_2)$ If yes continue with  $V_1 = V_1 \cup \{v\}$ et $V_2 = V_2 - \{v\}$.
- When improvement is no longer possible, return the cut $V_1, V_2$

1 . How can I prove that the algorithm is executed in polynomial time by displaying done at most $|E|$ iterations.

Let $(V_1,V_2)$ be a cut. For a $v \in V_1$ we call $\alpha(v)$ the neighbors of $v$ which are in $V_1$ and $\beta(v)$ the neighbors of $v$ which are in $V_2$.If $v \in V_2$, we set $\alpha(v)$ and $\beta(v)$ the neighbors of $v$ which are in $V_2$ and $V_1$ respectively.

2. How to prove that if the algorithm can no longer advance then for everything $v \in V$ we have $|\alpha(v)| \leq |\beta(v)|$​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is easy. As you say the algorithm can perform at most $O(|E|)$ iterations. Initially $c(V_1, V_2)=0$. Each iteration, except the last, increases $c(V_1, V_2)$ by at least $1$. The claim follows since $c(V_1, V_2) \le |E|$.

2) Suppose that, for some $v \in V_1$, $|\alpha(v)| > |\beta(v)|$ Then moving $v$ from $V_1$ to $V_2$ increases the value of $c(V_1, V_2)$ by $|\alpha(v)|$ and decreases it by $|\beta(v)|$, therefore $c(V_1 \setminus \{v\}, V_2 \cup \{v \}) = c(V_1, V_2) + |\alpha(v)| - |\beta(v)| > c(V_1, V_2)$. This shows that  the algorithm could not have terminated. The case $v \in V_2$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your response Steven, demonstrating that $c(V_1,V_2) = (\sum_{v \in V} \beta(v))/2$,  it's possible to have an approximation ratio of 2 ?

Comment: Isn't it always the case that $c(V_1,V_2)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{v \in V} |\beta(v)|$? Each edge $(u,v)$ across the cut $(V_1,V_2)$ contributes $1$ to $c(V_1,V_2)$, and $2$ to $\sum_{v\in V}|\beta(V)| $ (i.e., $1$ in $|\beta(u)|$ and $1$ in $|\beta(v)|$).
The fact that the algorithm is a $2$ approximation follows from $|E|=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{v \in V}|\beta(v)|+\frac12\sum_{v\in V}|\alpha(v)|\le\frac12\sum_{v \in V} |\beta(v)|+\frac12\sum_{v\in V}|\beta(v)|=\sum_{v \in V}|\beta(v)| =2c(V_1, v_2)$. Therefore $c(V_1,V_2)\ge\frac{|E|}{2}\ge\frac{c(V_1^*,V_2^*)}{2}$, where $(V_1^*,V_2^*)$ is a max cut.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's clear to me, can I ask you a few things, I have to finish my reading on the approximation this week, just to go faster I also asked a question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641138/approximation-of-job-scheduling but I have not yet returned , if you can still help me, Thank you